# Unexpected mask shape in TensorFlow 2 Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask

I have batch tensors of the shape `(batch_size, n_time_steps, n_features, n_channels)`. They arise from tensors of the shape `(n_time_steps, n_features, n_channels)`, where `n_time_steps` is *not constant*. When constructing the batches, the tensors are padded to the maximum value of `n_time_steps`.

These tensors should be fed into a neural network of the following architecture:

1. The inputs are masked due to the padding.
2. The tensors for each timestep are fed to a time-distributed CNN block. The mask is propagated.
3. The extracted features are fed to an RNN.

In the last layer, I run into an error due to the fact that the mask has the shape `(batch_size, n_time_steps, n_features)`, but the RNN expects it to have shape `(batch_size, n_time_steps)`.

Does anybody know how to get the mask of the appropriate shape?

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class TimeDistributedMaskPropagating(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed):
    """TimeDistributed layer that propagates mask."""
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        
    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return mask

n_features = 3
n_channels = 1

cnn_block = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
estimator = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, n_features, n_channels)),
    tf.keras.layers.Masking(),
    TimeDistributedMaskPropagating(cnn_block),
    # tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10)
    # yields ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 10
])

x1 = tf.random.uniform((4, 3, 1))       # shape: 4, 3, 1
x2 = tf.random.uniform((3, 3, 1))       # shape: 3, 3, 1

paddings = tf.constant([[0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]])
padded_x2 = tf.pad(x2, paddings)        # shape: 4, 3, 1
mini_batch = tf.stack((x1, padded_x2))  # shape: 2, 4, 3, 1

logits = estimator(mini_batch)          # shape: 2, 4, 3
print(logits._keras_mask)               # shape: 2, 4, 3
# mask has shape 2, 4, 3 with values
# [[[ True  True  True]
#   [ True  True  True]
#   [ True  True  True]
#   [ True  True  True]]
# 
#  [[ True  True  True]
#   [ True  True  True]
#   [ True  True  True]
#   [False False False]]]

# mask should have shape 2, 4 with values
# [[ True  True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True False]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the implementation of `tensorflow.keras.layers.Masking`, only the last axis is requested to have all values equal to the `mask_value` in order to produce an entry `False` in the mask. Accordingly, the tensor rank of the mask becomes the tensor rank of the input tensor minus 1 (and not 2, one for the `batch_size` and one for the `time_steps`, as expected).

The issue may be solved by defining a custom masking layer, where `axis=-1` from the original code in the methods `compute_mask` and `call` is replaced by `axis=[2, 3]` (in my case) or, more generally, by `axis=list(range(2, len(inputs.shape)))`.

Here is the full code:

```py
class CustomMasking(Layer):

    def __init__(self, mask_value=0., **kwargs):
        super(CustomMasking, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.mask_value = mask_value
        self._compute_output_and_mask_jointly = True

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return K.any(math_ops.not_equal(inputs, self.mask_value),
                     axis=list(range(2, len(inputs.shape))))

    def call(self, inputs):
        axes = list(range(2, len(inputs.shape)))
        boolean_mask = K.any(math_ops.not_equal(inputs, self.mask_value),
                             axis=axes, keepdims=True)
        outputs = inputs * math_ops.cast(boolean_mask, inputs.dtype)
        # Compute the mask and outputs simultaneously.
        outputs._keras_mask = array_ops.squeeze(boolean_mask, axis=axes)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
        return outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'mask_value': self.mask_value}
        base_config = super(Masking, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```